# Fade in a partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc asp.net c# app

I have 2 pages.

The 1st page loads.

On that 1st page the user can press a button that calls my jquery function.
This function loads a partial view.

This works well

What I thought would look good is to fade/blend from 1st div contents to 2 div contents.

Can this be done?

Part of my _Layout.cshtml page:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    @RenderBody()           
</div>
```

My index page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{Html.RenderPartial("Welcome2", null); }
```

My Welcome2 page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome2";
    Layout = null;
}

<div id="#content1">
    @Html.Hidden("MyURL", @Url.Action("Lite", "Service"))
    <div id="divWelcome" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <div id="headerimg" style="position: relative;">
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom:250px; left:30px; width: 550px; font-family:DIN; font-size:23pt; font-weight:600; color: white; letter-spacing:0.01em;">
                We offer Cloud solutions for small businesses to help them manage their workflow requirements
            </div>

            <hr style="position: absolute;height:6px; width: 490px; bottom:200px; left:30px; " />

            <div style="position: absolute;width: 550px; bottom:150px; left:30px;  font-family:DIN; font-size:14pt; font-weight:500; color: white; letter-spacing:0.01em;">
                Our core sectors of expertise are professional services, data management and outsourcing.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my jquery function:

```
$("#my_button").click(function () {
    $('#mainContent').load(url);
    return false;
});
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Welcome");
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    return View();
}

[Route("~/Welcome")]
public ActionResult Welcome()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome Page";
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("~/Welcome2")]
public ActionResult Welcome2()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

I appreciate that the answer lays in my jquery function but thought I would post the whole thing in case asked to do so

EDIT:

Change jquery to this:

```
$("#divHomeBanner").click(function () {
    var url = '/Welcome2';    
    $('#divPager').load(url);
    $('#divPager').show('slow')
    return false;
});
```

and in my layout to this:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <div id="divPager" style="display:none;"></div>
    @RenderBody()           
</div>
```

but nothing changed - the page did not show

Comment: Load it into a hidden element and then use the `.show('slow")` method (or one of the other `speed` options of `.show()`)

Comment: I did that but nothing happened nothing showed. will edit my question with that change

Comment: worked it out - thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _nothing showed_? But you should be doing it in the success callback - `$('#divPager').load(url, function() { $('#divPager').show('slow'); })`

Comment: thanks-new to allthis. makes sense